# How to convert image buffer to file object in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, file, imagemagick-convert

**Purpose**

How do I make a file in the same path in NodeJS in the same form as client request form?

```
// test.js 
const readFile = fs.readFileSync(filepath, (err, data) => {
if (err) {
    console.log(err)
} else {
    return data
} })
// result : <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a ..... >
mysdk(readFile)
// error : it need to file name, size(bytes) , type ...
```

I want File object like this.

[image]

File locate

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved...

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const filepath = path.join(__dirname, './success.png')
const image = fs.createReadStream(filepath)
// now image converted like file object...
```

Comment: image variable is now a ReadStream, not a File object. And there is no way to cast it to File. What do you mean by "now image converted like file object"?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are looking for something like this

```js
const process = require('process');
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const express = require('express');

const cwd = process.cwd();
const app = express();
const PORT = 9091;

app.get('/read-file', async(req, res) => {
  const rawFileData = 'data:image/png;base64,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';
  var fileData = rawFileData.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
  var buffer = Buffer.from(fileData, 'base64');
  const newFileName = 'nodejs.png';
  // now buffer contains the contents of the file we just read
  await fs.writeFile(`./${newFileName}`, buffer, 'utf-8').then( () => {
    res.status(200).sendFile(`${cwd}/${newFileName}`);
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`server listening on port: ${PORT}`)
});
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtReE.jpg)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The written code appears to be for response to the client( FE ). However, internally, file objects must be passed to other APIs. 
What I want is convert to an image(png/jpg..) in the same path to file object.